# IntelliJ doesn't run updated code and runs code from previous branch

Tags: java, python, docker, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have a project that uses a Java test framework (cucumber) to run against a Python job (does some SQL querying) 
The project is build with Gradle and spins up a docker instance for the Python environment to run the tests against.

However debugging is proving difficult because When I make chances to the python code it is not picked up when rerunning the tests - resulting in the same result (failure) as the previous run.

I noticed the Build files are not being updated, but even when i have done this manually and re-ran the tests again I get the same result.

I have tried 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' but had no joy. 
I have tried reimporting the project but no joy. 
I then tried to swap branch back to master and ran the 'working' tests but got a failed result that would only have come from the code in the feature branch.

My knowledge is a limited but a logical guess is the code is being packaged/wrapped up somewhere and not being refreshed(cached) on each test run.
I have also tried deleting IntelliJ's run configuration for the tests.

So I am now a little lost to where it could be caching this so I can clear it and hopefully it picks up the new changes.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try : File > Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 0):

Did you looked in the gradle build output? try running the gradle build with --info, that will show you if the gradle build identify the changes in the python files or not.
If not , add the python sources to jar task dependencies:

```
task createJar(type: Jar) {

inputs.files(myPythonfolder)
..
```

it can also be achieved by adding new task with input files on the python sources and adding dependency between the jar task and the python task:

```
jar.dependsOn myPythonTask
```

for more accurate details , add the build.gradle file of your project here